# Sending form data

Tags: html, forms, contacts

I have the folloing contact form on my website but I am not sure how to make it work.

```
<form id="contact-form">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">
                                Email Address</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                                </span>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject">
                                Subject</label>
                            <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                                <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                                <option value="service">General Service</option>
                                <option value="suggestions">opt 1</option>
                                <option value="suggestions">opt 2</option>
                                <option value="suggestions">opt 3</option>
                                <option value="suggestions">opt 4</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="9" cols="25" required
                                placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-skin pull-right" id="btnContactUs">
                            Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: what is the problem ? and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: what do you mean by `"i have the folloing contact form on my website but not sure how to make it work "`

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/k084kojg/

Comment: By "Make it work" do you mean inserting the entries into a database or sending as an email?

Comment: You might need some server side handling. Did you realize that? If so, what are you using or can you use?

Comment: thats right i want the data to be sent via email

Answer (score 0):

There might be two things that you might be doing. Either handling the data on the same page(highly unlikely given your data) or send it to the server to process. Sending form to the server side can be done like this:

1."POST" the data to a PHP script running on the server. Refer to this
[Sending Retrieving form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

2. Using Javascript to send a form to server side PHP script. Refer to this link
   [Sending Forms through Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript)

I think you haven't used any PHP script on server side. Also there might not be Javascript function call to send this data to the server.
For a very basic tutorial on sending form data to server, Refer to this link
[Basic Form Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)